# How to speed up $group phase in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My query executes too slow:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate(
    {
        $unwind: '$preferableUsersIds'
    },
    {
        $addFields: {count:1}
    },
    {
        $group:{_id: '$preferableUsersIds', number:{$sum:"$count"}}
    },
    {
        $sort:{number:-1}
    },
    {
        $limit:1
    }
)
```

I noticed that `$group` the cause of this issue.
Can you advice approach to speed up it ?

### P.S.

According information in google I've read - adding indexes won't help

I can say that I tried  `db.pmusers.createIndex({preferableUsersIds:1});`

and `db.pmusers.createIndex({_id:1, preferableUsersIds:1});`

but this doesn't help

### P.S.2

explain:

```
 db.pmusers.aggregate( [{$unwind: '$preferableUsersIds' }, { $addFields: { cmp_value: {$cmp:['$id', '$preferableUsersIds']} } }, { $match: { cmp_value: {$eq: 0} } }], {explain:true} )
{
        "stages" : [
                {
                        "$cursor" : {
                                "query" : {

                                },
                                "queryPlanner" : {
                                        "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                        "namespace" : "mydb.pmusers",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {

                                        },
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                                                "direction" : "forward"
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$unwind" : {
                                "path" : "$preferableUsersIds"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$addFields" : {
                                "cmp_value" : {
                                        "$cmp" : [
                                                "$id",
                                                "$preferableUsersIds"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$match" : {
                                "cmp_value" : {
                                        "$eq" : 0
                                }
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: You can filter documents using $match before $group stag if possible. How many documents do you have in this collection? Try using explain on aggregation

Comment: @Astro pmusers = 100 000 elements. Each pmuser has 0-100 preferableUsersIds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `$group` can't use indexes, but you can do some things to make your pipeline more efficient by only projecting `preferableUsersIds` and removing the `$addFields` stage:

```
db.pmusers.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {_id: 0, 'preferableUsersIds': 1}
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$preferableUsersIds'
    },
    {
        $group:{_id: '$preferableUsersIds', number:{$sum: 1}}
    },
    {
        $sort:{number:-1}
    },
    {
        $limit:1
    }
])
```

Unfortunately this still can't use an index as only `$match` and `$sort` can do that when used at the beginning of the pipeline.

Comment: I trust you but from first glance I don't see performance boost

Comment: @gstackoverflow Because it still can't use an index, all the docs must still be read from disk which is the performance drag.

Comment: @JohnnyHK ,  I have tried the way you suggested, unfortunately it didn't improve